# Invalid or unknown request type (not a Dialogflow v1 or v2 webhook request)

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, webhooks, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am working with dialogflow for a chatbot app.
But when I run NodeJS always response with error

> Invalid or unknown request type (not a Dialogflow v1 or v2 webhook request)

in the line where I declare the agent.

This is the original code. What is wrong?? :(

```
    'use strict';
    const express = require("express");
    bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const app = express();

    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    const { WebhookClient } = require("dialogflow-fulfillment");

    var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

    app.post("/order", express.json(), function (req, res) {
      // Error on next line
      const agent = new WebhookClient({ request: req, response: res });

      console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(req.headers));
      console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));

      function welcome(agent) {
          agent.add(`Welcome to my agent!`);
      }

      function fallback(agent) {
          agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
          agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
      }

      let intentMap = new Map();
      intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
      intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);

      agent.handleRequest(intentMap); 
    })

    app.get('/hello', function (req, res) {
        res.send ('Hello World');
     })

    app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log("Listening port: " + port);
    })
```

Comment: The line where NodeJS indicate the fail is in declaratio of agent:  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request: req, response: res });

Comment: Does it happen when you run node and don't do anything else? Or does it happen when you test? If you're testing it, how are you doing so?

Comment: Ultimately, the problem was in the testing process I was using.
 All the code is correct, but it runs only with Dialogflow callbacks, because using webhook receives JSON data, and my test process was doing it with REST from http.
Many thanks for everything!!